# ContourPlot: Setting Global Options for Bar Legend

Tags: plotting, options

I'm looking to specify the appearance of contour plots globally in my Mathematica notebook. This is easily done with `SetOptions`:

```
SetOptions[ContourPlot, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math",
FontSize -> 14}];
```

However, this does not apply to `BarLegend`:

```
 ContourPlot[Abs[Gamma[u + I v]], {u, -1.5, 1.5}, 
{v, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Contour plot of Gamma function.]

I have tried to set global options for `BarLegend`:

```
SetOptions[BarLegend, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily 
-> "Latin Modern Math", FontSize -> 14}];
```

but this seems to have no effect! How can I achieve this?

PS: Using v.10.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the options had to be specified for the ContourPlot itself:

```
SetOptions[ ContourPlot, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math", 
FontSize -> 14}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily 
-> "Latin Modern Math", FontSize -> 14}];
```

**Important:** Specifying `LabelStyle` in your plots will automatically over rule this so the `BarLegend` will have a different style to the `ContourPlot`. This was actually the source of much confusion.

Hope this is at least helpful to someone.